# How do I keep the zeros in a formatted QString?

Tags: qt, qt4

I am trying to keep the trailing zeros on a QString formatted as currency. My current code will change *1234* to *$1,234*. But, what I want is *$1,234.00*.

Here is what is not working for me:

```
lndtBillRate->setText(QString("$%L1").arg(lndtBillRate->text().toDouble(), 0, 'f', 2));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code should work as expected. Could the value be getting truncated in the widget that is displaying the text?

```
>>> from PyQt4.QtCore import *
>>> QString('$%L1').arg(1234.0, 0, 'f', 2)
PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'$1234.00')
```